# Custom Json.Net Converter using streamreader instead of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I was wondering if there was any examples on how to make a custom JsonConverter for asp net using JSON.Net that uses a TextReader or a StreamReader instead of just a string. For example there are examples like this http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm
that use custom JsonConvert class :

```
string json =
"{
    "Keys": [
    "FirstName",
    "LastName",
    "Roles"
  ],
  "FirstName": "James",
  "LastName": "Newton-King",
  "Roles": [
    "Admin"
  ]
}"
Employee newEmployee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(Employee)));
```

However I was wondering if it was possible to deserialize the json like this which uses a stream reader :
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

```
// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  // somehow make serializer use a custom JsonConverter
  Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
  // hoping that movie2 contains the custom converted json
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a `JsonSerializer` using `JsonSerializerSettings` with the desired converters:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(Employee)) },
};
var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
```

Then use the serializer as you currently are doing to read directly from the stream.

Reference: the docs for [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault_1.htm).

If you don't want to use the [global default settings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm), use [`JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create_1.htm) instead.   However `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` *does* use the global defaults, so switching from `DeserializeObject<T>` to `JsonSerializer.Create()` might result in a breaking change.  This small distinction is not mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) that you found.

Answer (score 1):

StreamReader has a ReadToEnd() function which returns a string.

```
string jsonString = file.ReadToEnd();
Movie movie2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This would definitely help because you could have properties, values, arrays, and entire objects not within the same line. Reading it as a stream could only give you a piece of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think i wanted to avoid using the ReadToEnd because I didn't want to bring the string into memory just in case it was a really long file. I will keep this in mind though